# Who is 'his' in following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, pronouns

his = Bhagwant Singh, am I right?

If I am right, why would he (Bhagwant Singh) dismantle his own fort?

> Upsurge in Hathras (1817)
>
> Dayaram, a talukdar of several villages in the district of Aligarh,
> had a strong base in the fort of Hathras. The fort, considered to be
> among the strongest in India—a ‘second Bharatpur’—had walls of
> great height, and thickness, defended by a deep ditch and artillery
> mounted at the top. The English had concluded the settlement of
> Hathras estate with Dayaram as a farmer. But due to progressively
> increasing high revenues, Dayaram constantly failed to pay arrears and
> even committed many acts of hostility by giving harbour to government
> fugitives. So, the Company with a large army attacked Hathras in
> February 1817. Dayaram fought bravely for more than 15 days and
> escaped unharmed. But, ultimately, he was obliged to come back on
> condition of submission and settled down with a pension. Another noted
> rebel **Bhagwant Singh**, Raja of Mursan, frightened to dismantle **his**
> fort, submitted to the government.  [(source)](https://www.dhammaias.com/foundation-courses/modern-india/chapter-29-peoples-resistance-against-britishers-before-1857-revolt)

Comment: I;ve added a link to the source.  It is always a good idea to do this.

Comment: @Kate Bunting  It seems that here is grametical error? Because fort must be destroy by company forces, why someone distroy his fort, infinitive must be in passive, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very idiomatic.  I'd read it as saying that Bhagwant Singh was afraid that he would have to dismantle his fort if he resisted the Company forces. So he surrendered without a fight. This assumes the author has used some non-idomatic phrasing.

It is possible that the author intended to say that Bhagwant Singh was frightened into dismantling his fort (by seeing the harsh treatment of his neighbour) and (having dismantled it) submitted. Again this reading assumes that there are some errors in the phrasing.

Comment: you mean, he didn't want that fort would have been dismantle by company forces

Comment: why he dismantle his own fort?

Comment: It doesn't say that he _did_ dismantle it, it says he was afraid to do so. Presumably he was afraid that the fort would be destroyed if he resisted the government forces.

Comment: @Kate Bunting  It seems that  here is grametical error? Because fort must be destroy by company forces, why someone distroy his fort, infinitive must be in passive, am I right?

Comment: As James has already noted, the sentence is not idiomatic (not a natural way to express the idea). There is no grammatical error, but the sentence only makes sense if we understand it to mean that Bhagwant Singh was afraid that his fort might _be dismantled._

Comment: He would have to dismantle his own fort if the British army captured his princedom and threaten to kill him if he didn't dismantle it.  He didn't want this so he signed a treaty with the British.